# How to use session storage to get value from an object and push into an other object

Tags: javascript, arrays, session-cookies

Well, my question is in my title, I'm actually trying to create various objects with a relationship based from the back-end `Java`. 
Class User is in `Many to Many` relationship with Class Budget and Class Transaction is in `One to Many`.

When I'm trying to create a user object with values and watch if the user is created in the database, it's working.
When I'm trying to create a user object with a budget object with values into it with also a transaction object with values into the budget object that's working.

My problem is right now I'm trying to create a transaction. I was thinking about using the `sessionStorage` instead of `array.push()` to create only a transaction. But I'm stuck with the both solutions.

from below my Js test. and my Front end console result.

thanks.

[image]

```
<script>
        $("#formulaire").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

          // 1ère etape test en dur //

          var username= "Steven";
          var  password= "Seagal";
          var lastName= "Seagal";
          var firstName ="SSeag";
          var pass = "123";
          var mail = "StevenSeagal@hotmail.fr";
          var budget = [{

            "budgetName": "food",
            "currentValue": 100.0,
            "administrator": 1,
            "transactions": [{ "debit": true, "transactionName": "Bière", "transactionValue": 10.0 }],
            "initialValue": 200.0}];

          // faire un json//
          //2 creer un objet test//
          // erreur de [] au lieu de {} sacre Kalpesh :) //
          var user={};
           var userid = user.id=1;
           var username =user.username=username;
           var  userPaswword =user.password=password;
           var lasName= user.lastName=lastName;
           var firstName= user.firstName=firstName;
           var pass= user.pass=pass;
           var mailuser = user.mail=mail;
           var userbudget = user.budget=budget;
           console.log(user);

          // test//

          //3 requete ajax//

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
         // objet que je lui envoie //
         data: JSON.stringify(user),
         contentType: "application/json",
         url:"http://localhost:8080/user/createbody"
          }).done(function(data){
            console.log("envoi effectuer");
            sessionStorage.setItem('id',user.id);
          });
        });

          //Methode GET ALL
         $("#allUser").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/user/all",

          }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var recupData =JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(recupData);
          });
        });

        //
        $("#oneUser").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/user/1",

            }).done(function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              var recupData = JSON.stringify(data);
              console.log(recupData);
            });
          }); 
          //Methode createTransaction
            //valeur en dur d'une transaction  

       $("#createTransaction").click(function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();




/*
            const animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

         const count = animals.push('cows');
         console.log(count);
         // expected output: 4
         console.log(animals);
         // expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows"]

         animals.push('chickens', 'cats', 'dogs');
         console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows", "chickens", "cats", "dogs"]

*/



            var debit= true; 
            var transactionName="Bière" 
            var transactionValue = 10.0;
            //initialisation object & affectation
            var transactions=[];
            var usernameSession = sessionStorage.getItem('id');

          $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/user/"+usernameSession+"",
          }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
          })

          /*
            transactions.debit=debit;
            transactions.transactionName=transactionName;
            transactions.transactionValue=transactionValue;
            */

                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  // objet que je lui envoie //
                  data: JSON.stringify(transactions),
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  url: "http://localhost:8080/user/createbody"
                }).done(function (data) {
                  console.log("envoi effectuer");
                });
              });









</script>
```

Comment: I'm not looking terribly closely at what you've posted here, but I do see various things like "password" and so let me caution you that client-side session storage is *not* "secure" and should not be used for anything that you wouldn't want the user (or, a hacker with a file-editor) to get their hands on!

Answer (score 0):

You should save the value in an object before passing .

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('id','dfd');
var obj = {};
obj= sessionStorage.getItem('id');
alert (obj)
```